# CMS WYSIWYG Editors - What techniques do you use to client-proof these types of pages?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, wysiwyg, expressionengine, prestashop

This is a topic that may be considered something not necessarily "programming related"; however, I feel it is since I'm asking for specific techniques.

Essentially, as a web developer, I work with a variety of platforms that include a WYSIWYG editor in the backend (TinyMCE, WYGWAM, etc) and one of the selling points of such systems is that it becomes easier to manage your own content because of these tools.

In theory, sounds great, in practice, not so much.

It can be way too easy for a client to break a layout by using many of the advanced features of a WYSIWYG editor. They can start floating things, setting too much margin/padding, etc.

Generally, I have tried to build any of these types of pages with only some sensible default styles applied to a few of the most common tags, such as setting a font size, colors, some margins, and some text decorations.

I would like to know if anyone has used anything more advanced to essentially turn the output of:

```
$cms->getContent();
```

...or equivalent into something that is effectively sandboxed and operates entirely agnostic of any other style/layout elements being used.

As often as possible, I express to clients that they should purchase an HTML/CSS book for Dummies and read it so that they aren't deer in headlights when they click "code view" in a WYSIWYG. But I know they don't do this, nor do they hire anyone who has experience, and it ends up allowing a client more control than they should responsibly have.

Plus, it sucks when you are using their sites as work samples to show others knowing they have the ability to take your beautiful design and development and make it look like crap.

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

- I have a standard WYGWAM config that I reuse on new sites by importing the exp_wygwam_configs table.
- I keep options very limited in the editors
- Areas of the page delineated for images should use a File field, with an image resizer like CE Image used to insure proper size
- Client training. Make videos with Camtasia or similar tool if you have to.
- Use a custom stylesheet for WYGWAM that has a small subset of styles, so they can choose h2...h4, for example, but not h1 or h5.

Answer (score 1):

After encountering a lot of issues with WYSIWYG editors (which, by the way, never reflect accurately what you "get" in the end), I now prefer to leave only the most basic formatting features in the editor's configuration. For example, take a look at stackoverflow's editor.
It's got the following features: bold, italic, link, quote, pictures, lists, and alignments. The only special feature here are code sample and html, which are targeted to this site's audience. Most of your client don't need them.

I think it's the best approach, because if you give your clients the feeling that they can do whatever they want in the page, but in the end, this content is filtered when the page is rendered, they are going to be really frustrated. Not to mention the fact that the site will be slowed by the filtering process and the need to put the filtered content in cache.

Sometimes the client indeed wants to have a special layout in a page, but I think that can be best done by customizing the CMS so that it fits the client need.